# Is this possible in mysql (join two tables and filter out repeated data)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables [shipments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo9pr.jpg) and [transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTysE.jpg) each with a composite key of the order id and the shipment or transaction id. I am trying to make a [joined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYxA3.jpg) that contains all the data in a certain way. Your help and insight is much appreciated.

Comment: That's not how SQL works. MySQL doesn't have nested structures. Each row must be able to exist in isolation of any other row. Blanking out some of the values would make those rows unintelligible in their own right. So, the question becomes, why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Your attachments are incorrect. It leads to same picture

Comment: @MatBailie I am pulling this data to a spreadsheet for my team to see and review. I am afraid having two tables would confuse them instead of one were all the data is in.

Comment: @4EACH I believe the photos I have attached are correct.

Comment: If you're trying to brutalise SQL to compensate for a lack of aptitude in the team, the solution is to train the team.  For example, your desired result state that shipment 510 is associated to transaction 407, and that shipment 511 is associated to transaction 408.  Those associations, however, are not true.

Comment: I am not trying to do any analysis on the output data, the main purpose of this is to have a simple overview or a summary for them to see. @MatBailie

Comment: It's still not how SQL works. If you want to mangle your data in a way SQL isn't designed for, you're best advised not doing it in SQL.

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried to achieve that "joined table"? What is that "certain way" it should look like?

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get and it still remotely make sense is to use something like `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`...

```
SELECT
  s.order_id,
  s.shipments,
  t.transactions
FROM
(
  SELECT order_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(shipment_id) AS shipments
    FROM shipments
GROUP BY order_id
)
  s
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT order_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(transaction_id) AS transactions
    FROM transactions
GROUP BY order_id
)
  t
    ON t.order_id = s.order_id
```

| order_id | shipments | transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [501,502] | [401] |
| 2 | [503] | [402] |
| 3 | [504,505,506] | [403] |
| 4 | [507] | [404] |
| 5 | [508] | [405,406] |

But, then indexing, searching, etc, those arrays becomes a pain in the butt.

Generally speaking, what you're trying to do is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I am pulling this data to node first before pushing it to the desired spreadsheet. Do you think it would be a better idea to manipulate the two tables in node instead?

Comment: @maanDawod I still maintain that it's a mistake. I wouldn't aim for stated structure at all. As per my other comments, your structure states associations that simply don't exist. If you want to do that, that's your business. But SQL isn't designed to do it, because as a data structure it simply makes no sense. So, if the array format here isn't suitable, and you insist on the mangled structure, for which SQL isn't suited, you have few choices but to do it in a different layer of your application.

Comment: That SQL isn't suited to this should ring alarm bells that your target structure makes no sense for representation of that data. A language all about representing data doesn't support your intent, what does that say about your intent?

Comment: I get your frustration and I am fully aware that this structure doesn't make sense from a programmer point of view. I am new to SQL and I am not fully aware what and what I can't do with it, thanks for the insight.